# How to get back an MSSQL stored procedure result in php

Tags: php, sql, stored-procedures

i have an stored procedure database which check the password and get back a result as 0 or 1

how can i get that result in php?

```
    $this->data_selectdb(DB_ACC);
    $stmt = mssql_init('cabal_sp_IsValidPassword_by_ID');

    mssql_bind($stmt, '@UserID', $accountName ,  SQLVARCHAR,  false,  false,  50);
    mssql_bind($stmt, '@Password',  $accountPassword,  SQLVARCHAR,  false,  false,     32);

    mssql_execute($stmt);

    mssql_free_statement($stmt);
```

stored procedure:

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[cabal_sp_IsValidPassword_by_ID](@UserID varchar(50), @Password    varchar(32))
AS
BEGIN    
DECLARE @Result int
SET @Result = 0

DECLARE @EncryptPassword varbinary(255)
SELECT @EncryptPassword = Password FROM cabal_auth_table with(nolock) WHERE ID =    @UserID

IF(@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
BEGIN
    SET @Result  = PWDCOMPARE(@Password, @EncryptPassword)
END

SELECT @Result
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = mssql_execute($stmt);
```

Then this to get the rows from the result:

```
while($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result))
{ 
    ...
}
```

I've never used this function before, I've always just used the mssql_query function but according to one of the comments on [this page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mssql-execute.php), the code I gave above should work. Let me know if it works.